# libibverbs Hello World

Tags: infiniband, rdma

I'm trying to find a short "Hello World" example that uses Infiniband with libibverbs. [This](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/libs/infiniband/libibverbs/+/libibverbs-1.1.7/examples) goes into a good direction, but writing "Hello World" to the terminal should be possible in less than 800 lines. I was hoping for something like [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Networking_in_UNIX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps try using `librdmacm`. It wraps some of libibverbs functionality and especially assists in setting up connections. The rdma_server and rdma_client [examples](http://git.openfabrics.org/?p=~shefty/librdmacm.git;a=tree;f=examples/examples;h=dd0bfdfcc2051523d0ca4b138cf21e38f4ecd7c1;hb=HEAD) take less than 200 lines each.